# Use custom (unicode) fonts in WebView for my Android app

Tags: java, android, unicode, webview, android-studio-2.1

I wanted to use custom fonts in my Android app, custom fonts in `TextView` works fine but I couldn't find a way to add custom (unicode) fonts in `WebView`, I have tried every way possible but failed, take a look at my code to see whether I missed something. Thankyou.!

I've created a CSS file with custom font-family in asset folder and called it with `LoadDataWithBaseURL` but it doesn't work.

```
        htmlTextView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.htmlTextView);

        String text = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" />";
        htmlTextView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", text, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

        htmlTextView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        htmlTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        htmlTextView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(
                WebHelper.getWebViewFontSize(this));
```

CSS file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'iskoola pota';
  src: url('fonts/iskpota.ttf')  format('truetype');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a way put your html code in index.html file

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html");
```

html look like this. call your css file from asset folder

```
<html>
<head><LINK href="file:///android_asset/css/myStyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/></head>
<body>
    <img class="img" src="file:///android_asset/img/ok.png">
    <p > This above image is  shown from assets folder... </p>
    <p>Custom font <span style="color:red">'trado'</span> from asset folder has been applied on this text</p>
</body>
```

and css will look like this, you need to put your font file in asset folder ..

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: trado;
    src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/trado.ttf');
}
```

hope it works .. for  complete example on github [click](https://github.com/Jolpai/My-Webview)

Comment: I don't want to use html file, I just want to use a custom (unicode) font for posts in my wordpress based android app.